# Why is finding square root of perfect square $O(M(n))$

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

I saw [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9706/complexity-of-finding-the-square-root-of-a-perfect-square) question and its answer on Theoretical Computer Science stack exchange and I can't understand why the complexity of finding the root is the same as that of a multiplication. My thought was that we may need more than $O(1)$ multiplications to find the root (using Newton's Iteration as stated in the answer, since the method may need more than $O(1)$ steps).

Is there an upper limit not depending on $n$ to the amount of multiplications we may need? Or a method to find the root with enough accuracy(which means finding the actual root) after $O(1)$ steps? Am I missing something?

Note: I didn't ask this on theoretical CS stack exchange, since it is supposed to be for professional researchers in CS and no one asked about this in the comments so assume it isn't a research level question even if it is about an explanation of one (research level question).

Comment: It looks like Newton's method needs $O(\log n)$ iterations, where $n$ is the number of bits in the number you're trying to find the square root of.  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method.)  I'm not sure why the running time is as quoted.

Comment: With better and better approximations, we need multiplicatiosn of smaller and smaller numbers, I think. Since the complexity of multiplication is *at least* linear in the number of bits, the collective cost of an $n$-bit multiplication, a $\frac n2$-bit multiplication, a $\frac n4$-bit multiplication etc. is not more than the cost of a $2n$-bit multiplication

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, but the win as sizes decrease depends con the cost of each multiplicatoin.